# PHP project open in browser by click on icon

Tags: php, windows, browser, xampp, localserver

I want to open

```
    http://localhost/php_project/
```

in browser, the project done in xampp local server.

How can I create an icon for desktop which double click open the link in the browser?

Comment: You mean like [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/create-desktop-shortcut-website)?

Comment: some one upvoted this?

Comment: @DaveChen yeah that can be used as an alternative. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**: Create shortcut in desktop.

Right Click inside on desktop or the drive.

New > Shortcut

[image: Set the link]

Click next set the icon name

After Save, open properties by click on the shortcut icon and you can change the icon.

Comment: drag and drop is faster

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your server is running you can have a batch file,

```
@echo off
set /p var = "type your project folder"
start "Firefox" "path to firefox\firefox.exe" %var%
start "Google Chrome" "path to Google\Chrome\chrome.exe" %var%
exit
```

You can find the syntaxes for IE and Opera and Safari etc online.
You can also create a shortcut and put the location as 
     "path to your browser.exe" "URL"

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/481924/)  is an answer that might help.